# SAS: Converting a dataset from rows into columns

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset where each row represent a contact to a doctor for some person ID. Each ID have a different number of contacts (ie. rows). My dataset looks as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6h96.jpg)

What I want to do is end up with a dataset, that looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFX98.jpg)

That is for each unique ID  I want to have a dataset, where I create columns for each contact number (NUMBER) and what that type of contact is (CONTACT_TYPE), and the columns should be named based on the number of contact. I also want the code to be automatically create columns based on the ID with the largest number of contacts (MAX) i.e. NUMBER&MAX should be my last column.

I have attempted to somehow convert the NUMBER into a macro-variable 'Name' and that then attempted to somehow

%let name = NUMBER

and then used this in a datastep to do something like

NUMBER&name. = CONTACT_TYPE

in a data step. However, this has not worked for me, and is most likely very inefficient I suspect.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Regards Alexander

Comment: Next time post the data as text in the question. Preferable in the form of a data step.

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem is exactly what PROC TRANSPOSE is designed to handle.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=NUMBER ;
  by id;
  id number ;
  var contact_type;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished with `PROC TRANSPOSE`.

First, let's create a column with the new column name.

```
data temp;
set have;
_name_ = catt("NUMBER",number);
run;
```

Sort the data if it is not already.  Skip if the data is sorted.

```
proc sort data=temp;
by id number;
run;
```

Then run transpose

```
proc transpose data=temp out=want;
by id;
var CONTACT_TYPE;
id _NAME_;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for.